# Make bottom tabs using Sencha GXT

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt, uibinder

I have such problem - need to make widget that will look like panel with some stuff on it and bottom tabs. I saw pretty same tabs at Sencha Examples overview but I couldn't find any example code of them. Especially using UiBinder. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an appeareance:

```
new TabPanel(GWT.<TabPanelAppearance> create(BlueTabPanelBottomAppearance.class));
```

Hope that helps